# How to retrieve all rows from Parse in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, recursion, parse-platform

I've tried to retrieve all rows from my table by following the example at:
http://alexefish.tumblr.com/post/29843064002/fetching-every-row-of-a-table-with-parse-and-pfquery

... on iOS7 is crashes with an exc_bad_access the line weakPointer() to call the loop one more time.

Do you know a fix for that?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: I simply get a exc_bad_access on the specified line when the block recursively tries to be called.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Answer (score 0):

We were having the same issue, so I ended up rewriting the code to avoid blocks, which weren't really necessary. The code was crashing because `weakPointer` became nil.

This code is in an extension of `PFQuery` but could be adapted in different ways too.

```
#import "PFQuery+Additions.h"

@implementation PFQuery (Additions)

- (void)findAllObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:(PFArrayResultBlock)block {
    self.limit = 1000;
    [self putObjectsWithSkip:0 into:[NSMutableArray array] block:block];
}

- (void)putObjectsWithSkip:(NSInteger)skip into:(NSMutableArray *)results block:(PFArrayResultBlock)block {
    self.skip = skip;

    [self findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            block(nil, error);
        }
        else {
            [results addObjectsFromArray:objects];
            if (objects.count == self.limit) {
                [self putObjectsWithSkip:(skip + self.limit) into:results block:block];
            }
            else {
                block(results, nil);
            }
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

I've tested this up to 5,600 objects. The limit of `skip` is 10,000 (a total of 11,000 objects) so we might need to adapt again soon.